# buenas tardes, tengo problemas con esta funcion en java alguien sabe que puede ser?

Tags: java, funciones

tengo que hacer que x sea mayor-igual a y con la constante d, en java me dice que la variable que creé "pasos" debe hacer el return por fuera del while pero entonces no me funcionaría el if

```
public static int saltos(int x, int y, int d) // x=10 - y = 85 d = 30 
    {
        
        int pasos = 0;
        int brincos = 0;
    
            while(x<=y)
            {
                brincos = x+d;
                pasos++;
                if(brincos >= y)
                    return pasos;
            }
            
    }
```

Comment: Estás modificando pasos dentro del while pero tu condición es sobre `brincos` y `y`. El compilador es sabio y encontró caminos en los que la condición del if no se cumple y no hay retorno explícito. Revisa la lógica de las iteraciones y condiciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicional a la clara respuesta de Alfabravo ,tu variable `brincos` debe acumular los valores de `x+d` en cada iteracion de tu bucle de lo contrario tendrás un loop por que cada vez brincos sera x+d =40

```
public static int saltos(int x, int y, int d){ // x=10 - y = 85 d = 30 {

    int pasos = 0;
    int brincos = 0;

        while(x<=y){
            brincos += x+d;//brincos acumula todas las sumas de x+d 
            pasos++;
            if(brincos >= y)
                return pasos;
            

        }  return pasos;
        
}
```

Comment: mil gracias por tu ayuda bro